# What is the practical use of Stream.empty?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

[`Stream#empty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#empty--) returns an empty sequential `Stream`. From [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-empty-java-examples/), I learnt that an empty stream might be useful to avoid null pointer exceptions while callings methods with stream parameters. However, I am not able to think of an example that can help me understand this statement clearly.

Comment: Suppose you need to return a `Stream` derived from a list. How would you return a `Stream` derived from an empty list?

Comment: Is `Stream#empty` called in this case?

Comment: What is the use of an empty list or an empty string, for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have a `Stream` with a `flatMap` operation containinig some logic, you want the possibility of calling `Stream#empty` if some condition is met

```
listOfLists.stream().flatMap(list -> {
    // complex business logic, maybe even extracted in another method
    return xxx ? someList.stream() : Stream.empty();
});
```

Another example would be, just like for `Optional<T>` to make the return safer in case of a method returning a `Stream<T>` (let's say a factory method)

```
public <T> Stream<T> makeFooStreamFrom(Object... parameters) {
    // decide on what to do based on the parameters
    return decisionMadeToReturnAnEmptyStream ? Stream.empty() : Stream.of(foo, bar);
}
```

As for the example of a method accepting `Stream` parameters, a good example can be given like this

```
public <T> void consumeStream(@NotNull Stream<T> stream) {
    // In this example, if this stream is null, you'll get a NullPointerException
    // However, if you make sure to invoke this method using Stream#empty
    // No need to worry about it
    // This is the security that Stream#empty will provide in this case
    stream.map(...).filter(...).forEach(...);
}
```

A fourth example brought by @daniu is when you have a nullable `List`. This is mostly relevant before [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9), as [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) introduced `Stream#ofNullable`, which BTW uses `Stream#empty` internally too

Here is its implementation which is also the fourth example

```
public static<T> Stream<T> ofNullable(T t) {
    return t == null ? Stream.empty()
                     : StreamSupport.stream(new Streams.StreamBuilderImpl<>(t), false);
}
```

---

We would think that the example hereabove is not relevant as it returns a `Stream` anyway, but the underlying implementation uses a constant named `EMPTY_SPLITERATOR` internally which will make for a gain in performance as it'll be reusable.

Comment: Our just the real Optional equivalent, `Stream = (list != null) ? list.stream : Stream.empty ()`.

Comment: Correct @daniu I'll add it, however since [tag:java-9], I'd expect people to use `Stream#ofNullable` for this

Comment: Note that `flatMap` explicitly allows the function to return `null` instead of `Stream.empty()`, to be treated the same. But people may prefer `Stream.empty()` as a matter of coding style. Further, you should not have “a nullable `List`”. Use an empty list instead. But, of course, `Collections.emptyList().stream()` also has to return a value, and it will be `Stream.empty()` in most implementations…